# Get Alternating Row Status From DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, row, status, alternating

if i change the backcolour of a datagridviewrow that belongs to a datagridview control using alternating row colours and i want to programatically change it back, how do i know if the row was a normal row or an alternating row so i know what colour to change it back to? is there a property i have missed?

Comment: Are you talking about changing it back server or client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... realised you can simply set the style back to the rowcelldefaultstyle and it will do the hard work for you.